# rails: how to silence a single warning in a method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I turn off this warning:

DEPRECATION WARNING: superclass_delegating_accessor is deprecated and will be removed from Rails 5.0 (use class_attribute instead). (called from block in  at /home/ubuntu/myapp/config/environments/development.rb:84)

I get a whole bunch of these. I am running a rake "task/job" like this:

```
rails runner "Tickets.new('foo').perform"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can silence these warning by setting following in your initializers or environment:

```
ActiveSupport::Deprecation.silenced = true
```